# React Speech Recognition - inserting the text to the memory by updating the state

Tags: reactjs, state, speech-recognition

There is a similar question but I can't comment on it so I opening a new one.
I am new to React and try to implement  React SpeechRecognition component for my app. The text should be in an input box. the code for it (from react doc [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition][1] - with span tag instead of an input):

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition from 'react-speech-recognition'
    
const propTypes = {
  // Props injected by SpeechRecognition
  transcript: PropTypes.string,
  resetTranscript: PropTypes.func,
  browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: PropTypes.bool
}

class Dictaphone extends Component {
  render() {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props

    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        <span>{transcript}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Dictaphone.propTypes = propTypes

export default SpeechRecognition(Dictaphone)
```

Now I try to update a state of text (a string) by the transcript (the words that have been already recognized) but I can't make it.
from an earlier question, someone suggested this:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  value={transcript}
  onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
/>
```

now when I speak, I do see the words in the input box,
so the final code should be :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import SpeechRecognition from "react-speech-recognition";

const propTypes = {
  // Props injected by SpeechRecognition
  transcript: PropTypes.string,
  resetTranscript: PropTypes.func,
  browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: PropTypes.bool
};

class Dictaphone extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         text: '',
         events: []
      }
    }

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log (event.target.value);
    this.setState( {text: event.target.value} );
  }

  render() {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props;
    
    if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        <input 
          className='bg-light-blue'
          type="text" 
          value={transcript} 
          onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)}
        />     
     </div>
    )
  }
}

Dictaphone.propTypes = propTypes;

export default SpeechRecognition(Dictaphone);
```

but when I `console.log(event.target.value)` which is text - I see nothing so I'm doing something wrong.
Note that if I just write in the render func:

```
render() {
    const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props;
    var x = transcript;
    console.log('x is ',x);
    console.log('x length is: ',x.length);
.....
```

it does console the transcript (x) but it's not what I want - I need to save it in text by updating the state.

any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want it to save in the text variable on the state object?

Comment: yes, something like: 
if the event is 'transcript' so update 'text' by:
 this.setState( {text: event.target.value} );

Comment: You'll have to use componentDidUpdate to get the updated value of transcript and then do a setState in the componentDidUpdate.
Can you create a codesandbox for this. I can type in the remaining code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store the transcript prop in your state you should do something like this.

```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     if(prevProps.transcript !== this.props.transcript){
       this.setState({
         text: this.props.transcript
       });
     }
   }
```

In your render method use `this.state.text` to show in the input value.
Also in your constructor do

```
this.state = {
  text: props.transcript
}
```

Comment: thanks!!
 why does it different from something general like this:  
    onInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log (event.target.value);
    this.setState( {text: event.target.value} );
  }
or in other words -should I always use componentDidUpdate  in any case of a change in my app instead of an inner function that I've made up?

Comment: For that to happen there has to be a callback from the library to update the prop.transcrpt.

Comment: Also there's something called finaltranscript in the library. See if you can use that. So that you dn't have to syncronize state with prop all the time.